# Uiview size in xib file is not normal

Tags: ios, xcode

When create a uiviewcontroller file in my xcode the uiview size becomes so larger than the default iphone screen size like this [image]

I can't figure out why it occurs and how resize to the default size of iphone.

Comment: This screen is defiantly for iPad check your project setting that you have not accidentally created project only for iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure while creating class this should be done

1. Target for iPad - Uncheck
2. with XIB for user interface - Check

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can do it easily. Click on the view in XIB go the fourth tab on the properties window (right side) Under simulated metrics the first accordian check the size parameter (would be 'none' by default) and change it to 'free form' when you want XIB of custom size.

[image]

Comment: you cant change the size of xib file.

Comment: thanks now I can change its size but Why it occurs? Since I didn't change any settings earlier?

Comment: Yes @Dolours it is because of that. You can change them here in XIB and if you want the same size to come up in your app you should use the initWithNibName: method of this XIB's class. Although you can resize your View controller programatically but thats quite difficult.

Comment: @dattu We can change the size of XIB then why do I have a option 'free form' in the size parameter??

Comment: there is no free form or none option there check again or put screenshot to prove it.

Comment: @dattu is the screenshot sufficient??